# Trying to set dropdown selected value equal to part of string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select dropdownlist selected value equal to certain value like below:

```
 ddlRemark.SelectedValue = ddlRemark.Items.FindByText("string").Value
```

Dropdownlist contains datatext values like

1)  `B - In case of no deduction on account of declaration under section 197A`

2) `C - In case of deduction of tax at higher rate due to non-availability of 
PAN`

My problem is to select that dropdown value programmatically which matches some string values which are fetched from somewhere else, from database in my case.

Values fetched are  like  `A` `B` `C` etc.

So, if I am having value of `B`, dropdownlist should be selected to `C - In case of deduction of tax at higher rate due to non-availability of PAN`

So, how to specify something as like in `ddlRemark.SelectedValue = ddlRemark.Items.FindByText("string").Value` in place of string.
E.g string can contain something like starts from A or from B, etc

Comment: Post your dropdownlist code to get an idea?

Answer (score 2):

DropDownLists Text and Values can be different

Imagine this is your ddl:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRemark" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="B">B - In case of no deduction on account of declaration under section 197A</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="C">C - In case of deduction of tax at higher rate due to non-availability of PAN</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

And use the values directly

```
if (ddlRemark.SelectedValue == "B")
    //your code
else if (ddlRemark.SelectedValue == "C") 
    //your code
else
    //...
```

Comment: It is not possible in my case as I am binding it to ID values for Value property